# Postman Collection integration with Gitlab not syncing or integration not running

Tags: git, gitlab, postman

I have integrated Gitlab with Postman and it has stored my collection file into Gitlab repo. However, I am not able to see further changes I am making into my Postman API collection.

I have followed following article https://blog.postman.com/better-practices-for-git-version-control-in-postman/ and https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2022/08/24/postman-integration-with-gitlab-makes-your-api-workflows-easier/

I assume it should work automatically, however I am not sure if I need to take any steps / action to commit the changes.

Also, I think the integration runs at some interval based on following screen

[image]

However, I don't find anywhere how often it runs or how to run it manually?

Any hint would be great to improve my postman workflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both of those linked articles are from a different feature, those start from an API and it's then linked to a git repo where you can push/pull changes. You have created an integration that just backs up your Collections. https://learning.postman.com/docs/integrations/available-integrations/gitlab/

Comment: @DannyDainton You're right we have used Backup related integration. I see that Sync integration doesn't list our workspace and project. Any idea why?

Comment: You're better off sending a message to help@postman.com or creating a new topic in the Postman Community Forum for a more specific answer. You'd be able to expand on the details more over there.